# Apply Pig UDF on single column and automatically generate all other columns

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, udf

I have a Pig UDF that converts Ebcidic characters to ASCII in my pipe separated data file.
I have hundreds of columns and I want my UDF to be applied on 70th column.
How can I apply the UDF on that particular column and get the column data replaced as ASCII in the dataset.

```
REGISTER pigudf-0.0.1.jar;
DEFINE Ebc2Asc com.z.pig.udf.Ebc2Asc;

A = LOAD '/user/T4/cobDump.txt' USING PigStorage('|');
B = FOREACH A GENERATE Ebc2Asc($71) as txt:chararray;
DUMP B;
```

If we call the script like above I am getting only the converted column as part of the result. How can I get all the columns along with the applied udf column.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been a while, but it sounds like you want to use a [range projection](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.1/basic.html#prexp) to automatically generate the other columns.  It should look something like:

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE $0 .. $70, Ebc2Asc($71) as txt:chararray, $72 .. ;
```